# Magento License Violation

Tags: magento-community, licensing, discussion, opensource

I know of a multi-billion dollar entity that has rebranded Magento 1 Community as their own creation and is then re-distributing to hundreds of unsuspecting customers who are not aware that they are indeed on Magento.

I believe this is a clear violation of Open Software License v. 3.0 (OSL-3.0)

"c) to distribute or communicate copies of the Original Work and Derivative Works to the public, with the proviso that copies of Original Work or Derivative Works that You distribute or communicate shall be licensed under this Open Software License"

Before reporting them first want to know if this is indeed a violation.

1. Sites are built on Magento Community.
2. All the admin panels have been altered to remove all mention of Magento.
3. Customers have no idea they are on Magento.
4. Organization is proudly stating in the press that the platform is their's.
5. I have documents to prove all of this.

Looking for feedback.

Comment: wowww..........

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a violation of terms of use. No other way to answer this question. Magento need to know with any evidence you have of supporting this claim.

Comment: How would I report this?

Comment: I've your not keen on telephone I'd go with technical support under this https://magento.com/contact-us they can always get you through to the right person

Answer (score 0):

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894266/is-it-legal-to-remove-magento-logo-and-trademarks-from-admin/5895269#5895269

> [According to
>   RoyRubin](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/44238/), a
>   Magento Team member it looks like that there is no need for you to
>   keep the logo in the templates of the [Community Edition](http://www.magentocommerce.com/product/community-edition):
>
> > The license does not require attribution on the templates. You should be fine to remove them and keep all copyright notices in the
> >     files.
>
> You should keep the copyright notices inside the source-code files
>   intact however. Please read the [OSL 3.0](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0) license to learn more
>   about your rights with the software.

Comment: Yes, I remove the Magento logo often from the sites we work on and replace with the companies logo. This is not the issue that is a violation. The issue at hand is that the organization is not telling their customers that the platform is Magento and they are not redistributing it as Open Souce, they are redistributing as their own proprietary platform that they built. If a customer fails to pay them their monthly fee they even take the platform away from the customer.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit outdated, but I know a company has rebranded and distributed Magento with closed-source license.
They are not selling an e-commerce, but a different kind of software, using Magento as the basis for they custom modules (all Magento modules).
I know they have been in the market for years and they haven't had any problem yet with Magento/Adobe.